# using onDelete with Doctrine 2

Tags: mapping, doctrine-orm, yaml, relation

I can't get the onDelete to work in Doctrine2 (with YAML Mapping).

I tried this relation in my `Product` class:

```
oneToOne:
    category:
      targetEntity: Category
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

But that doesn't work..

EDIT:

I've set the `ON DELETE: CASCADE` manually in the database

imported the YAML mapping with `doctrine:mapping:import`,

emptied the database

updated it from the schema with `doctrine:schema:update` and got no `ON DELETE` in the foreign key.. so looks like even Doctrine doesn't know how to do it lol..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, got it! I had to use `onDelete` inside `joinColumn`:

```
oneToOne:
    category:
        targetEntity: Category
        joinColumn:
            onDelete: CASCADE
```

Comment: onUpdate is no longer supported.

Answer (score 7):

This is the way to use `onDelete` in `joinTable`:

```
manyToMany:
    parameters:
        targetEntity: Fox\LandingBundle\Entity\Parameter
        cascade: ["persist","remove"]
        joinTable:
            name: subscriberBox_parameter
            joinColumns:
                subscriberBox_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                parameter_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: CASCADE
```